# Delete SSL Certificate without prompting the user

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have written some lines of code which will delete certificates from Certificate Store before installing a new one if that certificate already exists, as below:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite | OpenFlags.IncludeArchived);
            X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "CertName", false);

            if (certs.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var cert in certs)
                {
                    store.Remove(cert);
                }
}
```

But, each time a certificate will be detected before it is deleted it promts the user to press yes so the cert is deleted. Is it possible to delete the certs without asking the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to delete the certs without asking the user?

the short answer is NO. Certificate management (add/remove certs) in the `Current User\Trusted Root CAs` requires explicit user consent. This behavior is hardcoded in the `crypt32.dll` library.